# image icon not displaying for firebase push notification in android Pie

Tags: android, metadata, firebase-notifications

I have implemented the push notification and works fine in all os except Pie. In pie notification image is not displaying.

I have updated the default icon in manifiest.
I have updated the icon in code OnMessageRecived.

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher_new"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/white" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/channel_id"/>



   NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_new)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(secondText).setBigContentTitle(title))
                .setContentText(secondText)
                .setChannelId(channelId)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Are you sending image notifications from firebase console or through firebase notification api?

Comment: no , just a text notification but the app icon on the side is not displaying for Pie @nimi0112

Answer (score 0):

Implement your `NotificationCompat.Builder` like this:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent);
    notification.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notification_color));
} else { 
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
}
```